# Splitting on multiple delimiters but ignore emails, decimals and URLs

Tags: python, regex

I have this code where I split on different delimiters but still include at least one of the delimiters after a text.

So if I had multiple `!!!`, I only retain one after the text. Now if I add an email or URL, it splits on the dot, something I do not want.

How would I modify my regex to exclude dots in emails, decimals and URLs but still work the same?

```
import re 

text = "This is a test. I love it here!!!! I hate this weather!! What should I do?? It's great. My email is cmw@example.com. My website is www.example.com and it's been live for 2.5 months."

arr = re.split(r'(.*?[\.!\?;])', text)
arr = list(filter(lambda _: _ not in ['', ' ', None, '!', '.', '?', ';'], arr))

print(arr)
```

I believe using something like NLTKs `sent_tokenize` or any sentence tokenizer module works but I'd prefer if we didn't have to use that.

Output of example should be:

```
['This is a test.', ' I love it here!', ' I hate this weather!', ' What should I do?', " It's great.", ' My email is cmw@example.com.', " My website is www.example.com and it's been live for 2.5 months."]
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to split on one or more punctuation marks followed by a space, but not on punctuation marks not followed by a space?

Comment: Yes and no. If I have a sentence "Example sentence.Another sentence.", I still want to split that although there is no space after the punctuation. In the case of emails and urls where the dot is preceded and followed by text, I don't want to split that. The only splits I want should happen when the sentence ends; i.e., sentence ends with one or more of the delimiters I have. I edited my original post to include the output I want. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, however it makes it rather difficult, because you need some way to determine if `abc.def` is an email or URL, or two sentences. I doubt this can be done with regex alone.

Comment: Yes, part of the reason I wanted regex is because the text isn't always in English. There can be multiple languages not well supported by libraries such as NLTK. That's why I thought a regex would work best as I can partition the text in any language based on several delimiters then worry how to translate/process them later.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'(?=\S)(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)+|[^\s@]+@\S+\b|(?:htts?://|www\.)\S+\b|[^?!.])+[?!.]+', text)`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ4IMV/1/). Or, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZ4IMV/2/)

Comment: This works very well. If I have to add a newline character (or multiple) to split on, how would I add that?

Comment: To split on newline as well, I just looped over the split text in the list, called .split('\n') on each, then flattened the list of lists it generated into a list of strings using itertools.chain().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
text = "This is a test. I love it here!!!! I hate this weather!! What should I do?? It's great. My email is cmw@example.com. My website is www.example.com and it's been live for 2.5 months.Another sentence"

new_text = re.split(r'(?<=\w[^a-z0-9\s])\W*\s?(?=[A-Z])', text)
```

output

```
['This is a test.',
'I love it here!',
'I hate this weather!',
'What should I do?',
"It's great.",
'My email is cmw@example.com.',
"My website is www.example.com and it's been live for 2.5 months.",'Another sentence']
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but if I have to add newline (\n) as a delimiter, can that be integrated? I guess I'd have to split on newline first then split using your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the better `regex` module which supports the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` mechanism:

```
(?<=[^\s])\.(?=[^\s])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[.!?;]+
```

Within `Python`, this could be:

```
import regex as re
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=[^\s])\.(?=[^\s])(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[.!?;]+')

for chunk in pattern.split(your_text_here):
    print(chunk)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kgZtWl/1/).

---

Or, as you seem to want to be able to split on sentences, look into [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/):

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize

for sentence in sent_tokenize(your_text_here):
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: Thanks. As for NLTK, I thought of using it, but since the language of the text to be split isn't always in English, I thought it might capture some random characters in another language and split on that.